# How to assign a JPanel to JFrame in netbeans gui editor?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, jpanel

I have a JFrame with JMenuBar at the top.

I put a JPanel on my JFrame in the middle and call it **Panel1**.

Next I create another class called **Panel2** extended JPanel and I put some items on that.

Now on my JFrame when user chose one of the JMenuItem I want to assign **Panel1** to **Panel2** class which I created. Therefore I can see other panel in my JFrame somehow!

How can I do that?

In the class JFrame I have written:

```
JPanel Panel2 = new JPanel();
Panel1 = Panel2;
```

It's not working, any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `JPanel` has `FlowLayout` as default `LayoutManager`, implemented in API
- empty `JPanel` returns zero `PreferredSize`
- you can't add one `JPanel` to another by `Panel1 = Panel2;`, then second `JPanel` isn't added to 1st. `JPanel`, is required to `myPanel1.add(myPanel2)`
- carrefully with reserved Java words and methods names `Panel` is `java.awt.Panel`
- all important informations is in Oracle tutorials [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html), [How to Use Panels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) and [JPanel API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html)

Comment: to your previous question, to use CardLayout, invisible and prepared JPanels with competently layed JComponents can't caused memory consuption in the case that JComponents models are empty, value, items, elemets from models are removed for all invisible JPanels

Answer (score 1):

Several things.

A first remark. Better name the fields, methods, variables with an initial small letter. Very wide convention.

In the GUI editor for panel2 select "Custom creation code" and there you could type `new Panel2()`.

To dynamically exchange a JPanel panel1 with a Panel2 panel2, overwriting the variables would have no effect; the object of panel1 was added to some swing Container of the JFrame.

Do in the action handling of the menu item:

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        remove(panel1);
        panel1 = new Panel2();
        add(panel1);
        invalidate();
    }
});
```

Seldom done in praxis however.